# XpagesSBT WebSecurityStore not write user keys

Tags: facebook, xpages

I tried using the demo XPages SBT for understanding the operation dell'OAuth, my aim is to implement, in some of my XPages, Facebook and Twitter.
I read several guides on the subject but I have several problems:

1) I can not understand why the fields "Consumer Key" and "Consumer Secret" are not read in the database WebSecurityStorage.nsf but only in the faces-config.xml file.

2) when I access Facebook through the "XpagesSBT.nsf / FacebookClientAPI.xsp" (using access via the faces-config.xml) the data is not stored in the "User Keys".

I made several checks but failed to find a solution.
I use Lotus Domino 9.0.1 FP3 and the latest update of XPagesExtensionLibrary.

Do you have any idea?

This is a part of the file faces-config.xml:

```
    <!--
        Token store Memory implementation
    -->

    <managed-bean>
     <managed-bean-name>CredStore</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.MemoryStore</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

  <!--
        Password store memory implementation.
    -->
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>PasswordStore</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.security.credential.store.MemoryStore
        </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
  <!--
        Facebook
    -->
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>facebook</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.ibm.sbt.services.endpoints.FacebookEndpoint
        </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>url</property-name>
      <value>http://www.facebook.com/</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>serviceName</property-name>
      <value>Facebook</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>appId</property-name>
      <value>XPagesSBT</value>
    </managed-property>
    <!-- OAuth parameters -->
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>credentialStore</property-name>
      <value>CredStore</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>requestTokenURL</property-name>
      <value>https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/request_token</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>authorizationURL</property-name>
      <value>https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>accessTokenURL</property-name>
      <value>https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>consumerKey</property-name>
      <value>***************</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>consumerSecret</property-name>
      <value>*************************</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>signatureMethod</property-name>
      <value>HMAC-SHA1</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this from memory so hopefully this is relavent

First thing, are you sure it should be of class MemoryStore? This sounds like something that is just kept in memory and never persisted. Isn't there some other class available that represents a physical NSF store. (I could be wrong here)

Secondly, I don't think WebSecurityStore.nsf is a valid nsf anymore. I think it is now hardcoded into the system that it will only use the standard location of the Credential store which is **IBM_CredStore\credstore.nsf** (there can only be one on each server and it is in the same place). Here is a knowledge center article about [creating on a single server](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/secu_creating_the_credential_store_application_on_a_single_domino_server_t.html).

I hope this helps. Sorry I can't provide exact answers at the moment. I can return later today and edit this when I get some more time.
I wasted a couple of days on the SBT before giving up because of things like this, documentation is duplicated with old and new incompatible instructions, it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.